# Segfaults for both gcc-13 and clang on Apple Silicon

Tags: apple-silicon, gcc

I just upgraded to an Apple Silicon (M2) box, and both gcc-13 (installed via HomeBrew) and clang produce segfaults on just about anything. I don't know how to debug that and figure out what is going wrong. Since they both segfault, I'm guessing it's something obvious.